# Maven modules projects no longer showing as maven project inside the parent project

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I have this parent Maven project and inside it I have 6 modules, It was created on Eclipse Neon and there everything is showing correct regarding the project structure.

[image]

The problem is after putting the project on a SVN repository and importing in another Eclipse, in this case, all the modules inside the parent project no longer show as maven project but just a normal folder.

[image]

What could be wrong? Anything on Eclipse? Any plugin? This Eclipse with the wrong view is the latest one, java-2019-09.

I need ideas :)

Edit 1:
[image]

**Edit 2**:
[image]

Comment: Can you try Project -> Properties -> Build Path -> Source Tab and add the folders there manually. This might help

Comment: Does _File > Open Projects from File System..._ of the directory of the parent project fix your issue? Make sure in the view menu of the _Project Explorer_ the option _Projects Presentation > Hierarchical_ is chosen.

Comment: Note that there is an option for the project explorer whether it should show projects hierarchically.

Comment: @uSeruSher thanks for trying to help, but no, in the sub-project (the module) when I got to properties I only see what is in the screen I put on my **Edit 1**

Comment: @howlger thanks for your comment, but I tried all that, I changed to Hierarchical and didn't help, it's seems to be something related to the 'nature' of the module.

Comment: @franzisk You tried which steps? In both cases, it is strange that also the parent project is a Java project instead of a non-Java Maven project.

Comment: @howlger I tried everything :) - when I import from the File System it shows the same way it did before (considering that I am doing this on a different Eclipse, not the one the project was created), I tried Projects Presentation > Hierarchica/Flat.

Comment: @franzisk Please show the _File > Open Projects from File System..._ dialog.

Comment: @howlger see my **Edit 2**

Comment: Thanks a lot @howlger, that did the trick, but it seems that the Spring Nature in the .project file is not being recognized (it shows a warning)

Comment: @franzisk Maybe the in the new Eclipse you have [STS4 which does not require a project nature, but the project was created with STS3 with its own Spring project nature](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/49#issuecomment-382313388).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import the nested projects use ***File > Open Projects from File System...*** and choose as *Import source* the directory of the (already imported) parent project.

By the way, the parent project should be a *General* Maven project instead of a Java Maven project.